# Is there limitation for maximum number of files which can be uploaded in SharePoint location in one folder

Tags: sharepoint-2007

1. Is there limitation for maximum number of files which can be uploaded in SharePoint location in one folder.
2. Is there limitation for maximum number of folders/sub folders which can be created in SharePoint location.
3. Whether specific naming convention is required to be followed for folder/file creation in SharePoint(Special character allowed)?

Answer (score 2):

For #1: The maximum library limit is 30,000,000 documents.  The maximum practical limit for a single folder is 2000 files.  Sharepoint does not scale well beyond 1000 files per folder.

For #2: There's no practical limit for the number of subfolders.  Your folder structure will become unmanageable well before you reach the limit.  The complete URL for the file or folder cannot be longer than 260 characters.  Note that this includes the server, site and library name.

For #3: You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a folder name or a server name: 
 `~ # % & * { } \ : < > ? / | "`

File names and folder names cannot be longer than 128 characters.

**References:**

http://old.markharrison.co.uk/blog/2004/09/sharepoint-scaling-limits.htm

http://blogs.officezealot.com/legault/archive/2007/04/26/20302.aspx

Comment: I doubt that practical limit of 2000 files per forlder is true. Just create views that has RowLimit property set <= 2000 and filter on indexed columns + order to see documents you are interested in: http://www.infoq.com/articles/SharePoint-Andreas-Grabner

Answer (score 0):

**URL length limitations in SharePoint Server 2010 and Internet Explorer**

The limitations In this section apply to the total length of the URL path to a folder or a file in SharePoint Server 2010 but not to the length of any parameters. Also, these limitations apply only to un-encoded URLs, not to encoded URLs. There is no limit to encoded URLs in SharePoint Server 2010. The limitations are the following:

•260 Unicode (UTF-16) code units – the characters in a full file path, not including a domain/server name.

•256 Unicode (UTF-16) code units – the characters in a full folder path, not including the file name and the domain/server name..

•128 Unicode (UTF-16) code units - characters in a path component, that is, a file or folder name.

•260 Unicode (UTF-16) code units – the characters in a full path, including a domain/server name for use with Office clients.

•256 Unicode (UTF-16) code units – the characters in a full path including the domain/server name, for use with Active X controls.

**More Info**
SP 2010
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564(v=office.14).aspx#limits

SP 2003 & 2007
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894630